# Web API Basic Authentication Issue on IIS 8 Running on Windows 2012R2

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple application developed with c# WinForm that uses HTTPClient to transact with Web API hosted in IIS 10 on Windows 10 during dev. Testing is ok on the dev computers. Now, I've moved the Web API application to a production server computer running Win2012R2. I have also configured the Web API on this production IIS to use only Basic Authentication. I see other IIS authentication schemes listed, including Digest, Forms, Windows, APS.Net Impersonation, and Anonymous, and have disabled all these. However, when I run the winform client application, I receive 401(Unauthorized) response. I've checked all settings and configuration I know to do, but still receiving this response code. I placed Fiddler in-between and noticed the response authentication is different from the one contained in the request. Example below:

Request Header:

```
POST http://rand22/PrevalonESB/api/Login HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic UFJFVkFMRU5U:cHJldmFsZW50Mg==
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: rand22
Content-Length: 105
Expect: 100-continue
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,nonce="+Upgraded+v138ac47246a9c7aabad1bf83ec86a95adeeacf04e0386d20192a696ef815b0d8b0e2486e724a2f04263a31a6878bc69aa78e0e6a56f57be8b",charset=utf-8,realm="Digest"
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 14:13:11 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I'll appreciate if someone here could help me diagnose what's happening. I'm also curious to know why the response header contain authentication scheme that I have disabled for the target web api application.
FYI: The server machine was formerly a domain controller but has been downgraded to a member server